Batch processing for face detection (MTCNN)
Is it possible to detect faces with mtcnn performing batch processing? I need to detect faces from 1 million images.
If it's possible, please share the ways to achieve that.

Is it possible? is a vague question that doesn't belong here. If I answer Yes, it is possible or No, it is not possible, will that be sufficient for you to accept it as correct and award me the bounty? Either of them would be a full, complete answer to the question you've asked.

Your edit isn't much better. If you hadn't bounty-protected it, it would be closed by now. You should read [ask], and then [edit] again.

According to this:
batch_boxes, batch_points = detect_face(
    img, self.min_face_size,
    self.pnet, self.rnet, self.onet,
    self.thresholds, self.factor,
    self.device
)

would do the batch-inference

Short answer:
mtcnn.detect(single_image)

can be changed to:
mtcnn.detect(batch_of_images)

Detailed Explanation:
The MTCNN model can handle both single images and batches of images using the same detect function. Reference
Single Image Detection:
from facenet_pytorch import MTCNN
import cv2

mtcnn = MTCNN()
single_image = cv2.imread('path_to_single_image.jpg')

boxes, probs = mtcnn.detect(single_image)

print("Boxes:", boxes)
print("Probabilities:", probs)

Batch Image Detection:
import os
from glob import glob
from facenet_pytorch import MTCNN
import cv2

# Initialize MTCNN model
mtcnn = MTCNN()

# Read images from a folder
image_folder = 'path_to_image_folder'
image_paths = glob(os.path.join(image_folder, '*.jpg'))

# Set batch size
batch_size = 64
results = []

# Process images in batches
for i in range(0, len(image_paths), batch_size):
    batch_of_images = [cv2.imread(img_path) for img_path in image_paths[i:i+batch_size]]
    results.append(mtcnn.detect(batch_of_images))

# Extract and print results
for i, (boxes, probs) in enumerate(results):
    for j, (box, prob) in enumerate(zip(boxes, probs)):
        print(f"Image {i*batch_size + j + 1} - Boxes: {box}, Probabilities: {prob}")

Cool part is, you don't need to resize all images into fixed shape. mtcnn handles it itself.
